# Remove some duplicates from list of objects given conditions

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list of Accounts as follows:

```
Accounts          ID
1000              123
1000              123
1000              456
2000              789
2000              789
```

I want to remove all occurrences of the duplicates if there are no multiple IDs for an account in the ID column. In this case only accounts 2000 should be removed. How do I achieve this in code?

Comment: .Distinct()....

Comment: Not totally sure I understand. Both 2000 accounts should be removed, but all three 1000 accounts should stay?

Comment: Yes that the idea. Account 1000 should stay because they are associated with multiple IDs

Comment: @User11040 - What should happen if there is an account with only one record? Should it stay or go? Say I had `new { Account = 1500, ID = 852 }` in your data above?

Comment: In that case it should go

Comment: @User11040 - In that case your question should read "I want to remove all records if there are no multiple IDs for an account in the ID column." Specifying duplicates is confusing and incorrect.

Comment: Yes thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `Accounts` and get the groups that have more than one distinct `ID`:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Accounts)
                 .Where(g => g.Skip(1).Any(x => x.ID != g.First().ID))
                 .SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
```

Comment: It's better to use `.Skip(1).Any()` rather than `.Count() > 1` to prevent the full iteration of the group.

Comment: thanks @Enigmativity, forgot about the deferred execution in `.Distinct()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with a statement like this:

```
accounts.Where(a => accounts.Any(b =>
     (b.Account == a.Account) && (b.ID != a.ID)));
```

Might not be the most optimal way if you have a large database, though.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much

Comment: Why a downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Aside from Distinct, you can also use Group By (sometimes the execution is also faster with larger data):

```
lstAccount= lstAccount.GroupBy(x => new {x.ID})
                             .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you test this?

Comment: Yes unless I miss something on the question.

Comment: The OP wants to remove both of the `2000` accounts - your solution keeps one.